# Node.js checksum vs body.length to detect file changes

Tags: javascript, node.js, checksum

I am writing some logic in a node.js script to detect whether a web page has changed in any way between two successive access times. I am using the 'request' module to pull and store a two copies of the page, then

1. generating a checksum and
2. looking at the body.length property of both pages.

In combination, this process seems reliable enough to determine whether the page has changed. I am using the 'crypto' module to generate checksums as described [here](http://blog.tompawlak.org/calculate-checksum-hash-nodejs-javascript)

However, I have noticed that some pages report a checksum change even though there are no visible changes and the length property is unchanged. What could be causing this?
Is there some inherent flaw in the 'crypto' method of checksum generation, in the createHash implementation or similar?

I suspect not, as the problematic pages are consistent (some always do, others always don't), pointing to the pages themselves.

Comment: You could try to diff if length is the same. See https://www.npmjs.org/package/diff . Maybe that will give some better idea.

Comment: diff is a handy module! I tried using jsondiffpatch earlier with no success. Anyway, as it turns out there is a logical explanation for why in two different cases body.length is similar but checksum is different. (1) One site uses ASP, the pages have a hidden input input element "VIEWSTATE" which varies from access time to access time but is always a hash of the same length, and (2) one site was throwing PHP errors about being unable to write session info due to a full disc, quoting the session hash, which again differs each access but is always the same length.